# JavaScript prints only the last element of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I want to loop inside `this.results`  which is a JSON coming from my server but my code prints only the last element of data

```
 let tempEvent = [];

  this.results.map(element => {
    tempEvent.push(element);
  });
  let arr = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < tempEvent.length; i++) {
    arr = [{ name: this.results[i].name }];

  }
  console.log(arr);
```

I already tried to do this:

```
for (let i = 0; i < tempEvent.length; i++) {
    arr += [{ name: this.results[i].name }];
}
```

But it gives me `[Object object]` and I don't know what that is.

Comment: Try doing `console.log(JSON.stringify(arr) )` instead. The array you're creating is an array of Objects, each with a `name` property and a value. So you're getting `[Object object]` because you're trying to output an object, and js needs to be told how to display that.

Comment: It also prints [Object object]

Comment: And I'm an idiot. Inside your for loop, do `arr.push({name: this.results[i].name}];` - otherwise, you're simply overwriting the array with the last member every time.

Comment: [`arr.push(…)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) is what you're looking for

Answer (score 1):

You are re-assigning the whole array. You can push the item in each iteration.

I also believe you want to push an object instead of another array here:

```
arr.push({ name: this.results[i].name });
```

**OR:** Use *index*

```
arr[i] = { name: this.results[i].name };
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like:

```
arr[i] = [{ name: this.results[i].name }];
```

or

```
arr.add([{ name: this.results[i].name }]);
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

Others have your answer in regard to why you only get the last element, but also you're using *map* the wrong way. It returns an array based on applying a callback to the elements of the array it's called on, so in this case:

```
let tempEvent = this.results.map(element => element);
```

which just copies the *results* array.  You're also throwing away the result of *map*, using it like *forEach*, which would be:

```
let tempEvent = [];
this.results.forEach(element => tempEvent.push(element));
```

There are many shorter ways to copy an array (no idea on performance but likely it's irrelevant), you might also do:

```
let tempEvent = [...this.results];
```

or

```
let tempEvent = Array.from(this.results);
```

and so on. Some code:

```js
let results = [0,1,2];

let tempEvent = results.map(element => element);
console.log(tempEvent);

tempEvent = [...results];
console.log(tempEvent)

tempEvent = Array.from(results);
console.log(tempEvent);
```

Note that while this copies the values in *results*, those values appear to be references to objects, it doesn't copy the actual objects. Modifying the object referenced by *tempEvent[i]* will also modify the object referenced by *results[i]* as they're the same object.